# Passing variable to a Select query in Oracle

Tags: oracle11g

I am working on Oracle 11g Db, Having trouble on writing Oracle syntax.

I am trying to pass a number variable to my select query and populate the select query to a cursor.

```
Declare yr_nr NUMBER;
Begin
yr_nr := 2014;
SELECT DCD.CCY ID, DCD.CCYCDDSC DSC
 FROM CCYDCD DCD, CCYEXC EXC
 WHERE DCD.CCY = EXC.CCY
 AND EXC.YEARNR = yr_nr
End
```

This select query returns 80 records. How to rewrite this syntax.

Comment: You use `yr_nr` and `v_yr_nr`. Is this a copy paste error? What kind of cursor do you expect - and what will you do with it?

Comment: Sorry just edited my query. It is yr_nr.

Comment: If i pass the EXC.YEARNR = 2014 , i get 80 records. I need to pass the year number through a variable

Comment: I have a cursor which will retrieve the select query

Comment: *how* do you get 80 records. The code as pasted is not valid, it throws `PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement`

Comment: when i ran just the select query.

Comment: SELECT DCD.CCY ID, DCD.CCYCDDSC DSC
 FROM CCYDCD DCD, CCYEXC EXC
 WHERE DCD.CCY = EXC.CCY
 AND EXC.YEARNR = 2014

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so what you have here is an anonymous block and everything that happens in the block stays in that block.  Kinda like Vegas.

In other words there is nothing to handle the result set from your query. When you do this:

```
declare

[varName] [type]

begin

    select foo from bar where column = var ;   <--- this has no place to go!

end
```

When you are at an sqlPlus prompt, sqlPlus has a default record set handler which then processes the returned record set and prints it to the screen.

When you use any third party tool like JDBC or Oracle's own OCI library those provide a record set handler then parse them to you with the appropriate calls to get the data, e.g.:

```
rs.getInteger([query],[column] ) //which returns the specific value.
```

That anonymous block is essentially a stored procedure.  So you have to have something to do with the result set.  This is the cause of the missing "into" error you are getting.

If on the other hand you did something like:

```
declare

  [varName] [type]
  result number ;
begin

    select count(foo) into result  from bar where column = var ;

end
```

The variable **result** would have the value of 80 since that is the number of records fetched.

```
declare

[varName] [type]
cursor thisCursor(p1 in number ) is select foo from bar where column = p1 ;    

begin

    for rec in thisCursor(varName) loop

       If rec.column = [some value] then
          doSomething
       end if ;

    end loop ;

end
```

Do this would allow you to do something with the result set.